# Cron doesn't write in log instantly on Ubuntu

Tags: logging, cron

I execute a Python script through `cron`. The script is containing many print statements from its beginning (first line is a print). However even if the script is running, the log file is created but remains blank.

Here is my crontab:

```
00 14 * * * python DE.py >> DElog.log 2>&1
```

Is anyone have a clue why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patience is a virtue.

For starters the log file gets created first, even before the script starts running and generating output.

Second on Linux when standard output gets redirected to something other than a TTY (a terminal window), the output will be fully buffered by default, rather than line buffered.

Because you also redirect standard error to stdout (with `2>&1`) no  output will be written to disk until:
- either your script completes
or
- the output exceeds the default buffer size (of 4k?).

You can adjust the buffering with [`stdbuff`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/stdbuf) and make the error and output modes unbuffered:

```
stdbuf -o0 -e0 python DE.py >> DElog.log 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

The log file exists and is blank because it is opened by the shell, even before the script runs.

See:

```
    $ rm log
rm: log: No such file or directory
    $ thatdoesnotexist > log
-bash: thatdoesnotexist: command not found
    $ ls log
log
```

So your script probably does not run at all.

First, for crontab, always specify the full path. So instead of

```
python DE.py
```

put something like (adjust the path of course)

```
python /usr/local/bin/DE.py
```

Same for the logfile: specify its full path.

Now you did not specify which crontab this is, which user? How did you enter these lines? Because you will need to make sure that the user under which this command will run has sufficient rights. It will need read access to read the python file and execute it and then it will need write access on the logfile path to be able to write to it.

These are the first step you need to fix.

Also, passing tip: with the bash shell,

```
 >> DElog.log 2>&1
```

can be simplified to

```
&>> DElog.log
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer and your tips! The script definitely runs because I can see the changes on a file it modifies, but I only get the logs when it's done or there is a error.